# Exception 'Attempting to JIT compile method, while running with --aot-only' with Google.ProtocolBuffersLite

Tags: ios, mono, unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers, aot

Im using Google.ProtocolBuffersLite in a class library that is used in my Unity3d project. 
When attempting to use ParseFrom(System.Byte[] data)  function within myClass.cs in the app on IOS I get the following exception:

```
---> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1 
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1<Google.ProtocolBuffers.ExtensionRegistry/ExtensionIntPair>:.ctor ()' while running with --aot-only.

  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer`1[Google.ProtocolBuffers.ExtensionRegistry+ExtensionIntPair]..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[Google.ProtocolBuffers.ExtensionRegistry+ExtensionIntPair,Google.ProtocolBuffers.IGeneratedExtensionLite].Init (Int32 capacity, IEqualityComparer`1 hcp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[Google.ProtocolBuffers.ExtensionRegistry+ExtensionIntPair,Google.ProtocolBuffers.IGeneratedExtensionLite]..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Google.ProtocolBuffers.ExtensionRegistry..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  Exception.Message: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Google.ProtocolBuffers.ExtensionRegistry
at Google.ProtocolBuffers.AbstractBuilderLite`2[TMessage,TBuilder].MergeFrom (System.Byte[] data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The procedure to use protocolBuffersLite was:

1. Add *option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;* in my .proto class
2. Generate .cs class using that .proto class and Google.ProtocolBuffers.dll version net20
3. Add to my library csharp proj the .cs class and the Google.ProtocolBuffersLite.dll
4. Compile with monoDevelop 2.8.2
5. Move myLibraryThatUseProtocol.dll and Google.ProtocolBuffersLite.dll to myUnity3d project
6. In Unity3D->Build Settings->IOS->PlayerSettings I use:

> Api Compatibility level: .net 2.0 subset
>
> Aot compilation options: empty
>
> Stripping level: Disabled
>
> Build app in Unity3d (version 4.2.0)
>
> Run app in Xcode
>
> I will be grateful for any help somebody can provide.

Comment: Hi from Uruguay, were you able to get this to work somehow?